# Character texture rendering in cocos2d-android

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I am developing a small android game and i want to know how to animate the character movement using cocos2d-android.

Thanks in advance

Comment: when you're using cocos2d-x then please only use the [cocos2d-x] tag, [cocos2d-iphone] and [cocos2d-android] are different engines using different languages

Comment: This question should be moved to cocos2d-android.

Comment: There is a Java example in  gamedev.stackexchange
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/30340/how-to-animate-the-sprite-along-with-action-in-cocos2d